# Help with php custom popup

Tags: javascript

Hi i have create a custom popup using javascript to use in PHP file. thw popup will appear when user click *My Special Website* i need to change the title header. Can help me how to do it??

```
//function:

function myPopup() {
window.open( "<?=$CFG->wwwroot.'/example.php';?>" ,"myWindow", " height = 300, width = 600, statusbar=0, scrollbars=0,resizable=0, location=0,status=0, directories=0, menubar =0, toolbar =0 , left = 262,top = 234" ) }

// call:  

<a href="#" onclick="myPopup() " >My Special WebSite </a> <span class="style1">*</span>
```

See my sample page:

Comment: This is **not** a question about PHP.

Comment: i put this script in PHP file..

Answer (score 0):

If the title is being served from the PHP page, you need to add the `<title>My Title</title>` to the page.

Comment: u r saying that it will follow what php page name is it?? can i just change the title separately/individually??